# When importing a URDF model, how are package:// URIs parsed?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using gzfactory to load a URDF in which mesh resources are specified using `package://ros_package/relative/path` URIs. Testing seems to indicate that Gazebo removes the `package://` identifier and treats the remaining string as a relative filesystem path. Is this what's really going on under the hood?.

TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1684/when-importing-a-urdf-model,-how-are-package://-uris-parsed?/) by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Current solution for reading URDF models in Gazebo assumes the ROS package containing the model must also have a valid [Gazebo `model.config` file](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__models__database.html) in addition to the [ROS manifest.xml file](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html).  And the model must be in both `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` and `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` for both ROS and Gazebo to find the model.

With that assumption, `package://` is simply replaced by `model://` by [parser_urdf.cc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3d057ec159d60aaff37dd03f4c2160853776d7d9/gazebo/sdf/interface/parser_urdf.cc?at=default#cl-711).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you do not want to have your model in two different places like @hsu said (`GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` and `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`) then what you can do is edit the launch file for your model's package, and after the  tag, but before you run any gazebo related stuff, insert an  tag which will allow you to temporarily set that environment variable, without changing across your entire system. http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/env

Here would be an example:

```
<launch>

  <env name="GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH" value="$(find surus_sim)"/>

  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find surus_sim)/robots/surus_sim.sdf" />
  <node
    name="spawn_model"
    pkg="gazebo_ros"
    type="spawn_model"
    args="-sdf -param robot_description -model surus_sim"
    output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

and then in your SDF (and i believe this would work for URDF too) you specify the path of your mesh(s) relative to the value specified in the  tag.

```
   <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <scale>1 1 1</scale>
        <uri>model://meshes/base_link.STL</uri>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
```

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1029/l0g1x/) with karma: 56 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kathrin@gazebo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5553/kathrin@gazebo/) on 2018-06-10**:
Hi,

I tried the Tutorial: "Using roslaunch to start Gazebo, world files and URDF models" but though exporting the environmental path to  ~/.bashrc and setting the export variables to the package.xml of test_gazebo and test_description I wasn't able to pulldown the tag in the model database in gazebo. I just followed the completely tutorial, adding the urdf model to the test_description package folder urdf.
Do you have an idea?
Thanks.